# undefined is not a function _reactNavigation.default(routeConfigs,drawerNavigatorConfig)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am creating a side menu using react-navigation. I am getting above error. When I google it, I got a solution that I must change the react-navigation version to 1.0.0-beta.23. I have done this. But, still, I am facing the same error.

My index.js,

```
import { AppRegistry, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import DrawerNavigator from 'react-navigation';
// import App from './App';
//Components
import HomeComponent from './components/HomeComponent';
import InfoComponent from './components/InfoComponent';
import SettingsComponent from './components/SettingsComponent';
import CloudComponent from './components/CloudComponent';
//Screen names
import { Home, Info, Settings, Cloud } from './screenNames';
//Screen size
var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

let routeConfigs = {
    Home: {
        path: '/',
        screen: HomeComponent,
    },
    Info: {
        path: '/info',
        screen: InfoComponent,
    },
    Settings: {
        screen: SettingsComponent,
    },
    Cloud: {
        screen: CloudComponent,
    },
};
let drawerNavigatorConfig = {    
    initialRouteName: Home,
    drawerWidth: width / 2,
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',  
    // drawerBackgroundColor: 'orange',
    contentOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'red',
    },
    order: [Info, Settings, Cloud, Home]
};
const App = DrawerNavigator(routeConfigs, drawerNavigatorConfig);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('tutorialProject', () => App);
```

Comment: Actually you're using a **_super old_** version of react-navigation, why not try with the latest version (3.6.1)?

Comment: @Jose, Initially I tired with new version only. But I faced the same issue. When I google it. Someone suggested using beta version in GitHub. So I have used an older version.

Comment: Now, I have tried with new version. Still same issue.